# How to disable/enable a DropDownList with a button using JavaScript in ASP

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

In a view, I have a DropDownList and a button.

Using javascript, when I click in the button,,,the dropdownlist became disabled.

But when I click second time in this button, the dropdownlist still disabled.

Is there any solution to make it enabled in the second click.

This is the code :

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedProfile_Ga, new SelectList(Model.Profile_GaItems, "ID_Gamme", "ID_Gamme"), new { @id = "gg" })%> 
 <input type="button" value="Configurer" id="btnShowGestion" onclick="GamDis()"/>
script type="text/javascript">

     function GamDis() {

         var gg = document.getElementById('gg');
         var bb = document.getElementById('btnShowGestion');


         gg.disabled = 'disabled';

     }

    </script>
```

Comment: @JohnH not the same but thanks , i found the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To re-enable the element, you need to remove the "disabled" attribute completely.

```
     if (gg.disabled) {
         gg.removeAttribute("disabled");
     } else {
        gg.disabled = 'disabled';
     }
```